How to apply shrinkage to non-centered second moment estimate
I have a set of $N$ samples $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ of random variable $X$, where $m$ and $N$ are comparable. I want to estimate the second moment matrix $\mathbb{E}\left[XX^T\right]$.
For the related problem of estimating the covariance around the mean $\mathbb{E}\left[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T\right]$ (where $\mu=\mathbb{E}[X]$), when $m$ and $N$ are comparable it is often desirable to not use the sample covariance directly, but to apply shrinkage in estimation, e.g. Ledoit-Wolf covariance estimation.
The thing I am wondering is how I would go about using such shrinkage methods for the non-centered second moment matrix. Since
$$\mathbb{E}\left[XX^T\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T\right] +\mu\mu^T$$
and denoting $A=\mathbb{E}\left[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T\right]$ and $B=\mu\mu^T$, I was thinking that one option is to:

Obtain $A$ using shrinkage
Obtain $B$ with the sample estimate of the mean
Add them together to obtain an estimate of $\mathbb{E}\left[XX^T\right]$ with shrinkage.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach or am I missing something?
